# Sqlite3 `step': constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to convert some JSON data and get it inserted into a sqlite3 db using Ruby. The JSON is coming from githubarchive.com I followed the advice on this question: [Escaping Strings For Ruby SQLite Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614236/escaping-strings-for-ruby-sqlite-insert) and my code looks like this:

```
Yajl::Parser.parse(open(input).read) do |event|
r = CSV::Row.new(headers, [])
flatmap({}, event).each do |k,v|
  v = (Time.parse(v).utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T') rescue '') if k =~ /_at$/
  if r.include? k
    r[k] = v
  else

   puts "Unknown field: #{k}, value: #{v}"
        end
    end 
#   tmp << r.to_s
db = SQLite3::Database.open( "../github.sqlite" )
val = (['?'] * 186).join(',')
ins = db.prepare("insert into Sheet1_copy values (#{val})")
ins.execute(r.to_s)
```

The top part of this is taken from their git project. Now, when I try to run this with any of the data, I get

```
gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:67:in `step': constraint failed (SQLite3::ConstraintException)
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using CSV::Row at all? Why not just use an Array?

Comment: working with code from here and trying to repurpose it: https://github.com/igrigorik/githubarchive.org/blob/master/bigquery/transform.rb So I need it to go from JSON to SQlite

Comment: Then go from JSON straight to SQLite and leave the CSV stuff out of it, it is just causing trouble.

Comment: @muistooshort I tried that, need a little guidance:    `js = File.open(input, "r")
Yajl::Parser.parse(js) do |event|
#  print event
db = SQLite3::Database.open( "../github.sqlite" )
val = (['?'] * 186).join(',')
ins = db.prepare("insert into Sheet1_copy values (#{val})")
ins.execute(event)
end`

Comment: I'd guess that you'll have to convert the Ruby booleans to 1 and 0 before you try to insert them into the database.

Comment: That's why I was trying to use what's already been done. If we look back at the CSV row.to_s, it's a flat string which should be able to be inserted in the db. It's a string similar to "val, val, val,...". I'm still very confused about what my original error was.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a few more things in place to load it correctly.. Here's a working copy: https://gist.github.com/2426614

Note that I'm not using prepared statements, since that would take a bit more gymnastics to fill in empty rows across all the different types of events. Having said that, it runs pretty darn fast as is.